# Linq-to-Sql query with group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

There is a table in database:

```
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [date_of_birth] [date] NOT NULL,
```

I need to get a datasource for GridView which contains 2 columns.

```
----------------
| age || count |
----------------
| 20  ||   3   |
| 21  ||   4   |
| 25  ||   5   |
----------------
```

Is it possible to do it with one query?

What I've tried:

```
            var dates = (from u in db.Users
                         group u by u.date_of_birth into g
                         select new { age = calculateAge(g.Key) }).ToList();

            var dates1 = from d in dates
                         group d by d.age into g
                         select new { age = g.Key, count = g.Count() };

            GridView1.DataSource = dates1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

This works but I think there is a way to make it more simpler. Or not?

P.S. calculateAge has the following signature

```
private int calculateAge(DateTime date_of_birth)
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all you have a logic flaw in the first query. You are using grouping by date, not by age, so peoples who born in same year but on different day will be grouped into different sets. This 'group by' is superseded by 2nd query 'group by' clause.
- 2nd thing to note is that your 2nd query will use actual results of 1st query (see ToList() call) so it will be running on .NET, not on SQL side.

Here is my vision for you query (count number of peoples with same age):

```
var dates = from u in db.Users
   select new { age = calculateAge(g.Key) } into ages
   group ages by ages.age into g
   select new { age = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

Or even without anonymous type declaration:

```
var dates = from u in db.Users
   select calculateAge(g.Key) into ages
   group ages by ages into g
   select new { age = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: It gives an exception Method 'Int32 calculateAge(System.DateTime)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: I am not very familiar with LinqToSql. But I am assuming that in your solution first grouping occurs on SQL side and select on .NET side. While in my solution there is are group by _after_ select.